# A particular text tagging system in Vim

Tags: vim, tags

Amongst other things I use Vim for my work reports. Not exactly reports but I cannot find a better word for it now. 
Those are of a form similar to

```
20-01-2015 14:43h
<bop> <modular system> <iva>
Text of report. Text of report. Text of report. Text of report. Text of report. Text of report. Text of report. Text of report. Text of report. Text of report. Text of report. Text of report. Text of report. Text of report. Text of report. Text of report. 

02-03-2015 14:43h
<pob> <some other tag> <some other tag 2>
Text of report. Text of report. Text of report. Text of report. Text of report. Text of report. Text of report. Text of report. Text of report. Text of report. Text of report. Text of report. Text of report. Text of report. Text of report. Text of report.
```

Date and time. Tags in second row, and the description that goes describing what was done.

Now this can get lengthy, since these entries are added several times a day, and the text can be significantly longer than two or three lines.

Several people read these, not all of them knowledgeable on the subject in hand. Often progress on some subject is tracked by tracking a certain tag, through the file. 
Since I often have other things on my mind as well, I sometimes make a mistake and instead of `<modular system>` tag write `<system modular>` tag which makes keeping history very difficult.

***So I am wondering, is there a way to use Vim's autocompletion to show a list of all tags (one or more words & numbers in < > brackets) so when adding those I can just pick them off the list, therefore avoiding the problem of mistyping them or mixing them up?***

Comment: Are those tags fixed or is it possible to add new tags on the fly?

Comment: @romainl - On the fly, that is, new tag can be created just by entering it in the text file for the first time. That is why I am asking,  by offering a list of tags already created people would not accidentally or on purpose create new ones, and the reports would be better organized/tagged.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach. It uses a separate tags file, so you can edit multiple report files and be able to use any tag in any file. It scans the files for tags and saves them as keys in a dict, so autocomplete should be quite fast. Save this as autoload/tagHelper.vim in your runtimepath, then call `tagHelper#AddAutocmds()` in your .vimrc. You'll have to set up global variables for the location of a tags file and the pattern to recognize these report files.

```
let tags = {}

if exists('g:tagFile')
    let tagFile = glob(g:tagFile)
else
    let tagFile = glob('~/tags.txt')
endif

if exists('g:reportPattern')
    let reportPattern = g:reportPattern
else
    let reportPattern = 'reports/*'
endif

function! tagHelper#LoadTags()
    try
        let taglist = readfile(tagFile)
    catch
        let taglist = []
    endtry
    for tag in taglist
        let tags[tag] = 1
    endfor
endfunction

function! tagHelper#AddMappings()
    inoremap <buffer> > ><Esc>:call tagHelper#AddTagsFromLine(getline('.'))<CR>a
    inoremap <buffer> < <<C-x><C-o>
    setlocal omnifunc=tagHelper#CompleteTag
endfunction

function! tagHelper#AddTagsFromLine(line)
    let matchStart = 0
    while matchStart != 0
        let nextMatchStart = match(a:line, '<[^>]\+>', matchStart)
        let tag = matchstr(a:line, '<[^>]\+>', matchStart)
        let tags[tag] = 1
        let matchStart = nextMatchStart + strlen(tag)
    endwhile
endfunction

function! tagHelper#AddAllTagsInBuffer()
    for line in getline(1, '$')
        call tagHelper#AddTagsFromLine(line)
    endfor
endfunction

function! tagHelper#CompleteTag(findstart, base)
    if a:findstart
        let line = getline('.')
        let col = col('.')
        let start = strridx(line, '<', col) + 1
        return start
    endif
    let matches = []
    for tag in keys(tags)
        if stridx(tolower(tag), tolower(a:base)) == 0
            call add(matches, tag)
        endif
    endfor
    return matches
endfunction

function! tagHelper#SaveTags()
    call writefile(keys(tags), tagFile)
endfunction


function! tagHelper#AddAutocmds()
    autocmd VimLeave call tagHelper#SaveTags()
    exe 'autocmd BufEnter ' . reportPattern . ' call tagHelper#AddAllTagsInBuffer()'
    exe 'autocmd BufEnter ' . reportPattern . ' call tagHelper#AddMappings()'
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

My [CompleteHelper library](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3914) makes it easy to build custom completions (and I've already written quite some); you'd need one to match any tag name inside `<...>`. But even though the library does the hard work of building the list of matches, you'd still have to write the boilerplate code to define the pattern, and assign this to a completion key.

So, prompted by your use case, I've written the [SpecialLocationComplete plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5120) that utilizes the CompleteHelper library and allows the definition of a custom completion via a simple configuration object. And best (for you), it even ships with a `CTRL-X CTRL-X T` completion for complete tags, just what you asked for (and what I imagine could be more generally useful for XML tags, too)!